# partial push with git?

Tags: git

I am a new git user.

Following some difficulty, I was able to get a solid workflow going so that I can push from my local repository to my website.

A problem however has come up. I develop on wamp and push to the site. When I push, my website database settings are being overwritten. Is there a way to use git selectively to avoid this.

I am using codeigniter, so specifically I would like to push the entire project the first time and then avoid pushing the application/config directory in future pushes

Thanks ,

Bill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database settings should not be in version control. Keep the settings in an untracked file instead. And of course you can have a similar file to show you which options are available.

So if the settings are in `settings.conf`, you can have a tracked file `settings.conf.example`.

Comment: I feel this answer is more direct to the problem. It specifically addresses the fact that some types of files in a project should not be tracked at all.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Arjan. Since I am kind of new to git would you mind giving more details on how to 'Keep the settings in an untracked file instead', assuming I start with a local git repo on wamp which I want to push to an empty website? I have also edited my original question with more details. Regards, Bill

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. Git tracks content not files, so you push all or nothing.
If there are files that you don't want to ever push, add them to the .gitignore file.

Comment: "any later changes will be ignored". That's false. Tracked files are still tracked even if you add them to `.gitignore`. You can do `git update-index --assume-unchanged file` for ignoring future local changes, but I think this may lead to problems when file is modified by new commits.